# Core Data lazy load to-one relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a problem with Core Data. I read around that Core Data is lazy to load entity relationships, in case this, has not a to-many relationship.

I have an entity "Item" which has a relationship (to-many relationship) with an entity "Movement".
[image]

In this method, addition to loading all instances of "Movement", I want to load the relative attributes of "Item", for example "name".

```
//Core data request
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Movement"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

NSFetchedResultsController *result = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                         managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                    cacheName:@"Root"];

[result performFetch: &error];
```

to see if it works, I added this code:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    Movement *movement = [array objectAtIndex:i]
    NSLog(@"item name %@",movement.movement_inItem.name);
}
```

the result is null *item name (null)*

I looked around, and tried to put this code under **[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];**

```
NSString *relationshipKeyPath = @"movement_inItem";
NSArray *keyPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:relationshipKeyPath];
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:keyPaths];
[fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];
```

but nothing changes.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot see an obvious error in your code. Perhaps you can NSLog() the values of `movement` and `movement.movement_inItem` in your loop.

Comment: you right! the movement_inItem is nil

Comment: That means that the relationship from the movement to the item is not set.

Comment: Yep, it was a my big mistake